# How to name two columns in join tables with two same foreign key at one table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in the MySQL Database:

**names**

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'John'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Mike'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Fred'}
]
```

**name_changes**

```
[
  {id: 1, old_name_id: 1, new_name_id: 2},
  {id: 1, old_name_id: 3, new_name_id: 1}
]
```

(names are foreign key to 'id' in table 'names')

Please, help me to build query for join those tables and get result:

```
[
  {id: 1, old_name_id: 1, new_name_id: 2, old_name: 'John', new_name: 'Mike'},
  {id: 1, old_name_id: 3, new_name_id: 1, old_name: 'Fred', new_name: 'John'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the table names two time and use a a proper table name alias

```
select  a.id id, a.old_name_id, a.new_name_id, b.name old_name, c.name new_name
from name_changes a
inner join  names b on b.id = a.old_name_id
inner join names c on c.id = a.new_name_id
```